# How to choose between posting a picture and providing its link?

Tags: discussion, images

Consider this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59657/which-variables-have-too-much-variation), where one answer from @EngrStudent brings a link to a nice picture of a bubble chart.

Although link usage usually makes questions / answers smaller, I thought in that case it would be very nice to have the picture appearing directly in the answer.

I have the impression that pictures and formulas encourage users'  participation: upvotes, comments, and even downvotes.

So, I know it also depends on the question and the picture to be posted, but:

1. Are there guidelines/patterns to follow when choosing between posting a picture or providing its link?
2. What would be the best option: embedded picture on a link, or the picture / chart themselves?

---

Edit: I forgot to look on SO's meta, and they DO have this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48636/should-pictures-be-linked-to-or-embedded) too. The most upvoted answer guides to post the picture directly, even though CV content is more theoretical than SO's.

Here is another [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9397/official-position-on-the-use-of-images-in-questions-and-answers) on SO, with accepted answers towards pictures being posted directly in threads.

Comment: Doesn't the edit answer your questions?

Comment: I was expecting to read other opinions to see if there would be different perspectives (or no), considering our theme "statistics".

Comment: If anything, wouldn't CV users be even more likely to think including (posting) graphics is good than SO users would?  ...so if the position on (M)SO is already pro-picture-posting, it seems pretty likely that ours would be too.  If you posted this just to subtly remind people that posted pictures can be helpful and linked pictures can be less so, though, I agree.  :)

Comment: @A.M., IMO, yes (but it is my feeling) and I do not have any arguments to support my feeling, hence, the question. Thank's for sharing your perspective.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

by image

[image: 1000 words]

Answer (score 0):

[by link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIdzL.png)